80's or 90's book series about two kids who learn to survive in a post-apocalyptic world
This would be an 80's or 90's book series. I was a kid and was told I couldn't read the young teen books. I did anyways, but haven't found the series again.
It started off in a small town with two kids at a local church theater. Bombs start dropping and they wake up later to a world destroyed. They had to learn to survive and fight. By the end they married and had kids but it was over the course of a few books.

I was going to suggest Fire Brats, but that series had no resolution. (The books just stopped coming.) You could look through Wikipedia’s list of nuclear holocaust fiction

Thank you very much. I will take a look there and see what I can find.
